# How to ignore field in Spray-json [Scala]

Tags: json, scala, spray

I'm using spray-json in SCALA. [SPRAY-Github](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) I want to exclude (ignore) some fields from json answer. What is the best practice?

```
package ru.steklopod

import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import ru.steklopod.entities.{Game, Helper}
import spray.json.{DefaultJsonProtocol, _}

trait MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val gameFormat = new JsonWriter[Game] {
    def write(g: Game): JsValue = {
      JsObject(
        "id" -> g.id.toJson,
        "next_step" -> JsNumber(g.nextStep),
        "won" -> g.won.toJson,
        "finished" -> JsBoolean(g.finished),
        "players" -> JsString(g.players),
        "steps" -> JsNumber(g.steps),
        "size" -> JsString(g.size),
        "crosses_length_to_win" -> JsNumber(g.crossesLengthToWin),
        "field" -> JsString(g.fieldPlay)
      )
    }
  }
}

class JsonTest extends FunSuite with MyJsonProtocol {
  test("JSON") {
    val game = new Game(1, None, false, "1, 2", 0, Helper.ThreeByThree.toString, 3, "0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0")
    val marshalled = game.toJson
    println(marshalled)
  }
}
```

The final marshalled object is:

```
{"players":"1, 2","size":"3, 3","field":"0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0","finished":false,"id":1,"next_step":1,"crosses_length_to_win":3,"steps":0,"won":null}
```

Comment: Can you modify `implicit val gameFormat`?(just delete the filed you don't in your output).

Comment: Yes I can, but I need a custom field names. `crossesLengthToWin` must be `crosses_length_to_win`. Also I can't delete, becouse in different places the answers also are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala, it is customary to process or modify complex immutable objects using an approach called a [lens/lenses](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Lens.html). There are some lens for spray-json: [gist](https://gist.github.com/kirked/5d795cbef7ada9457a50) and [library](https://github.com/jrudolph/json-lenses) .

Perhaps this is too difficult for your solution and you can just modify several fields from the JSON object ([JsObject.fields](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/36959ef06fa632945ff01aaa2cc558b6cc8365d7/src/main/scala/spray/json/JsValue.scala#L51)) and then create a new JSON object.